# How to convert a line that goes through the origin into Hough space?

Tags: computer-vision, transform, hough-transform

Assume that the lines are parameterized with an angle $\theta$ of the line normal and a distance $\rho$ from the origin:

[image]

For each of the lines in the image space below (left), draw the corresponding point in the Hough space (right). Use letters A, B, C and D to mark the points. You need to also write the point coordinates. Assume $\rho\geq0$ and $0^{\circ}\leq\theta<180^{\circ}$.

[image]

Now, the solution is:

[image]

I understand the theory behind the Hough transform.  **What I did**:

Line $A$ go through $(0,2)$ and $(2,0)$ so we get:
$$
m_{A}=\frac{2-0}{0-2}=-1
$$
Then we get:
$$
y-2=-1(x-0)\Leftrightarrow y=-x+2
$$
Lets find line $A'$ that goes through $(0,0)$ and is perpendicular to the line $A$. so $m_{A}\cdot m_{A'}=-1$ and then we get $m_{A'}=1$, so the line $A'$ is $y=x$. Lets find the meeting point:
$$
\begin{cases}
y=-x+2\\
y=x
\end{cases}\Rightarrow x=-x+2\Leftrightarrow2x=2\Leftrightarrow x=1
$$
also $y=1$, which means $(1,1)$ is the meeting point. Lets move to polar coordinates:
$$
\begin{cases}
\rho=\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}=\sqrt{1^{2}+1^{2}}=\sqrt{2}\\
\theta=\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)=\arctan\left(\frac{1}{1}\right)=\arctan(1)=45^{\circ}
\end{cases}
$$
This means that line $A$ is represented as $(\sqrt{2},45^{\circ})$ in the Hough space.

Let's move to point $B$ which represented by $x=3$. In that case $B'$ is $y=0$ and the meeting point is $(3,0)$. This means that:
$$
\begin{cases}
\rho=\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}=\sqrt{3^{2}+0^{2}}=3\\
\theta=\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)=\arctan\left(\frac{0}{3}\right)=\arctan(0)=0^{\circ}
\end{cases}
$$
This means that line $B$ is represented as $(3,0^{\circ})$ in the Hough space.

Now for line $C$ I'm not sure what to do. Since line $C$ is already coming from $(0,0)$, I'm not sure how $C'$ should look like and where the meeting point is located? They got a really strange point in the answer $(116,0)$, how did they got it? I'm guessing I'm missing some important formula here which сan save me from calculating the line equation $C'$ and the meeting point.